# Passing data to PHP script via AJAX function giving me errors?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Below is the AJAX/JS function in my file, and the main part of my PHP file. This function works perfectly when I take the POST variable out of the PHP script, but when I use POST to pass data to the PHP I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

JS SCRIPT:

```
var func = { "foo": 'bar' }
$(function(){
    $("#marking").on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            data: JSON.stringify(func),
            url: "functions.php",
        }).done(function( data ) {
            var result= $.parseJSON(data);
            var string='<table width="100%"><tr><th>Student</th> <th>Assignee</th><tr>';
            $.each( result, function( key, value ) {
                string += "<tr><td>"+value['studentEmail'] + "</td><td>"+value['peerEmail']+'</td> '+"</td> </tr>";
            });
            string += '</table>';
            $("#records").html(string);
            $("#records")[0].scrollIntoView();
        });
    });
});
```

PHP SCRIPT:

```
$cc ="TESTCS";
$at = "TEST";
$func = $_POST['foo'];
$result_array = array();

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection to database failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT studentEmail, peerEmail FROM submissions WHERE `assignmentName` = '$at' AND         `classCode` LIKE '$cc'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($result_array, $row);
    }
}
echo json_encode($result_array);
$conn->close();
```

Comment: While the cause of our problem is different, all the advice I gave [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66054031/157957) applies: break the problem down, look at each part of the code separately, and narrow down which part actually has a problem.

Comment: Also, please just use prepared statements.  https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encode your request as JSON then you need to do three things on the client:

- Encode the data (you are doing this)
- Set the request’s content type to `application/json`
- Use the POST request method and not GET

And one on the server:

- Write PHP to read the raw body and decode it. PHP will not populate `$_POST` with a JSON request body.

So don’t send JSON.

Pass the plain object to jQuery’s `data` property and let jQuery encode it as URL Form Encoded data (and set the correct content type automatically) which PHP *does* automatically populate `$_POST` with (you still need to set the request method correctly).

Comment: I'd add another bullet point... use a POST request instead of GET

Comment: Thanks, I previously used the data property and was given the same error. Here is what I used:                 data: {"foo": 'bar'},

Comment: @uahimself — And in a GET request `$_POST[‘foo’]` will still not be defined.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your help but I still am getting the same error using a POST request.

Comment: Those are all the obvious things wrong with your code. Try examining the value you are trying to parse as JSON.